# If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is nonempty, show that $A$ is not bounded above if $r\in A$ implies $\sqrt{r^2+1}\in A$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $r\in A$. Then form the sequence 
$$
r_1=r,r_2=\sqrt{r^2+1},\ldots,r_n=\sqrt{r_{n-1}^2+1},\ldots
$$
Observe $\sqrt{r^2+1}>r$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore this sequence is bounded below by the sequence $x_n=n$. Since $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, we must also have $r_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus $A$ cannot be bounded above. Is this right?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Just because $r_{n+1}\gt r_n$ why would $r_n$ be bounded below by $n$? For example $r_n=1-\frac1n$ which is convergent.

Comment: Consider the sequence $s_n=r_n^2$ instead.

Comment: What does the sequence $\;\{n\}\;$ have to do with the sequence $\;\{r_n\}\;$..?

Comment: It's bounded below by $x_n=n-1$ and $x_n$ is unbounded above.

Comment: Try with $r=1$ and see that it is not bounded below by the sequence you claim bounds it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\;A\;$ is bounded above, and let $\;M:=\sup A\;$, and let $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$. For simplicity assume $\;M\ge0\;$ Then there exists $\;a_n\in A\;\;$ s.t. $\;M-\frac1n<a_n<M\;$ (this follows at once from the definition of supremum), and passing to the limit and using the squeeze theorem we get that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=M\;$.

But then, by arithmetic of limits, $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{a_n^2+1}=\sqrt{M^2+1}>M\;$ , but this is impossible since $\;\sqrt{a_n^2+1}\in A\;$ and thus $\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,,\,\,\sqrt{a_n^2+1}\le M\;$ ...